# Unable to power an Arduino Pro Mini through the RAW pin

Tags: power, arduino-pro-mini

I've recently bought an Arduino Pro Mini, the 3.3V and 8MHz version. The first time I powered it, using the VCC pin, all worked. But, as soon as I attempt using the RAW pin instead, nothing lights up... Is my regulator broken ? Or is this a typical issue ?

Comment: What is the power source you are attempting to connect to the RAW pin?

Comment: @Majenko It's an unregulated 5V source

Comment: Check there is solder on the solder jumper SJ1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not completely familiar with that specific board, but according to the schematic there is a solder jumper which is used to isolate the RAW voltage regulator from the rest of the system "for low power applications".

[image]

I don't know off hand if that comes pre-soldered or not, but check it to make sure it is connected, otherwise the RAW input will do nothing.